# Create sql query - MSSQL with distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with columns Id,DoucmentId,Name,Created,MinorVersion,MajorVersion

with example data  :

```
GUID,1,'document1',GETDATE(),1,0)
GUID,1,'document1',GETDATE(),2,0)
GUID,1,'document1',GETDATE(),1,1)
GUID,2,'document2',GETDATE(),1,0)
```

In query i need get all unique with higest major and minor version :

```
GUID,1,'document1',GETDATE(),1,1)
GUID,2,'document2',GETDATE(),1,0)
```

I have this query, but i need return all column in table...

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
          DocumentId,
          MAX(MajorVersion),
          MAX(MinorVersion)
FROM ComDoc_Document
GROUP BY(DocumentId)
```

Is here some trick to get this?

Thanks for help

EDIT : My configuration is MSSQL 2008R2 standart

Comment: You don't need the distinct, the group by clause is enough if I understand you correctly.

Comment: Well, if i use standard group by SELECT ... FROM ComDoc_Document GROUP BY(DocumentId) I get 'Column 'ComDoc_Document.Created' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause' error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Id,DocumentId,Name,Created,MinorVersion,MajorVersion
FROM
(
SELECT *
    ,RANK() OVER 
    (PARTITION BY DocumentID ORDER BY MajorVersion DESC, MinorVersion DESC) AS 'RANK'
FROM ComDoc_Document
) tmp
WHERE RANK = 1
```

this also has the advantage that if you later decide to retrieve the last two revisions for each document, you just do `WHERE RANK <= 2`

Comment: Thanks for answer. I hear first time about rank t-sql functions.
Unfortunately this code reports me 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.' But thanks for new interesting information

Comment: @Mennion oops... I missed a "tmp" before the last WHERE clause (you need to give a name to the nested query). Corrected

Answer (score 1):

You need to join the original table with your result to get all columns:

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM ComDoc_Document AS t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT
                  DocumentId,
                  MAX(MajorVersion) AS MaxMajor,
                  MAX(MinorVersion) AS MaxMinor,
            FROM ComDoc_Document
            GROUP BY DocumentId) AS t2
ON (t1.DocumentID=t2.DocumentID AND t1.MajorVersion = t2.MaxMajor AND t1.MinorVersion = t2.MaxMinor)
```

Comment: won't you lose MAX(MajorVersion) and Max(MinorVersion) ? I think you should do SELECT t1.*, MaxMajor, MaxMinor FROM...

Comment: They are the same as t1.MajorVersion and t1.MinorVersion, as you can see in the join clause.

Answer (score 0):

you should not be able to do this. however mysql has bug, which allow you to take other column names as well. you can simple do ComDoc_Document.* (or just *) (you will not need documentid anymore). however as I said, it should not be able to work like this - what if you had in second column values "A", "B", "C" for the same documentid? which value should be returned? in principle you should be able to take only those values, for which you make group by or agregate function (like you do with MAX, MIN etc)

Comment: Thanks for answer. 
"it principle you should be able to take only those values, for which you make group by or agregate function". You are right, but later i need all column data and i can't load this data separately...

Comment: see Cularis solution + my comment